# Parsing and processing XML in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, xml

So I have a little XML document, foobar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "bar.dtd">
<title _FORMAT="XXX.XXX" _QUANTITY="1" _DEVICENAME="XXX" _JOBNAME="FOOBAR">
    <subtitle>
    <variable name="x">A-1234567</variable>
    </subtitle>
</title>
```

and a little Python,

```
    with open('foobar.xml', 'rt') as f:
        tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
    # Loop over all elements in 'tree' in section order
    for node in tree.getiterator():
        if node.tag == "variable":
            for z in range(number):
                if len(str(start)) == 7:
                    accession = "A-" + str(start)
                # This simply adds leading zeros if there are < 7 digits
                elif len(str(start)) < 7:
                    accession = "A-" + ("0" * (7 - len(str(start))) + str(start))
                start += 1
                # Assign 'accession' to the node text
                node.text = accession
                tree.write("foobar.xml")
        else:
            continue
```

that beautifully finds the node tag I'm interested in, and processes it by iterating over a range, each time replacing the node text and writing the XML to a file.  There's only one problem:  I need this to happen in Ruby.

So far I have

```
doc = Document.new(File.new("foobar.xml"))
doc.elements.each() do |element|
  element.elements.each() do |child|
    child.elements.each() do |sub| # probably wrong
      for z in 0...$number
        if $start.to_s.length == 7 
          accession = "A-" + $start.to_s
        else
          accession = "A-" + ("0" * (7 - $start.to_s.length)) + $start.to_s
        end
      $start += 1
      # need to assign here and write to file or assign to variable
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my first time processing XML in Ruby and I'm failing to really understand the syntax.  My goal is essentially replicate the Python, by changing the node text for each iteration of the loop, and then writing that out to an XML file.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Ooo, your Python is showing! :-) In Ruby we can ignore the parameter parenthesis if they're empty. `.each()` can more simply be written `each`. Ranges are used but `for z in 0...$number` would often be `0.upto($number-1) do |z| ... end` or `(0 ... $number).each` or `$number.times` or some other variation on the theme. I'm not sure what you're up to with the stuff inside the "for" loop, but you should look at [`String#format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005963), especially the `*` option, as in `%*0d` because it looks like you're doing some '0' padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's an REXML-based solution:

```
require 'rexml/document'
$number = 3
$start  = 1312

doc = REXML::Document.new(my_xml)
REXML::XPath.each(doc,'//variable') do |el|
  $number.times do
    el.text = "A-%07d" % $start
    File.open( "f-#{$start}.xml", 'w' ){ |f| f << doc }
    $start += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for my XML parsing in Ruby; it's fast and efficient to use (and lets you use CSS-style selectors instead of XPath if you like):

```
require 'nokogiri'
$number = 3
$start  = 134341

my_xml = IO.read('foobar.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(my_xml)
doc.css('variable').each do |el|
  $number.times do
    # Pads to a 7-digit number: see `ri Kernel#sprintf`
    el.content = "A-%07d" % $start
    File.open( "foobar-#{$start}.xml", 'w' ) do |f|
      f << doc
    end
    $start += 1
  end
end
```

I modified the above to write out a unique file; surely you don't write the same file again and again, right?

Comment: You can do something very similar to the above using REXML if you use the xpath expression `//variable` to find all elements named 'variable' at any depth in the document.

Comment: Thank you for the effort.  Are there any alternatives?  I couldn't get Ruby to use nokogiri.

Comment: Update: Phrogz, it finally worked.  Of course I had to add "require 'rubygems'" for it to work.  Many thanks.

Comment: @mbm, that would be because you are using Ruby < 1.9. Rubies > 1.9 automatically `include 'rubygems'` for you.